# filename return empty codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have form to upload images in php, when i save the path and name, the name returns empty field in table database here is my code and the value in my database always empty field, please help me

Registration controller

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
class Registration extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->helper('form');
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('/registration/daftar');

    }

    function add_user() {
        $this->load->model('/daftar/Daftar_Model');
        $image_path = APPPATH. 'user_images/';
        $config['upload_path']   = $image_path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']      = '500';
        $config['max_height']    = '450';
        $config['max_width']     = '450';
        //$config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $path = $this->upload->data();
        $image_name1 = $path['file_name'];
        $image_path1 = $path['file_path'];
        //$this->upload->do_upload('foto');
        //$photo_data = $this->upload->data();

        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'no_telepon' => $this->input->post('no_telepon'),
            'alamat' => $this->input->post('alamat'),
            'image_path' => $image_path1,
            'image_name' => $image_name1
            );

        $this->db->select('username');
        $this->db->where('username', $data['username']);
        $result = $this->db->get('user');

        if($result->num_rows() > 0) {
            echo "Udah ada";
            $this->output->set_header('refresh:2; url='.site_url("/registration"));

        } else {
            if(! $this->upload->do_upload('foto')) {
                var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
                //$this->load->view('/registration/daftar', $error);
            } else {
                //$data1 = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $this->Daftar_Model->insert($data);
                echo "Registrasi Berhasil";
                $this->output->set_header('refresh:2; url='.site_url("/login"));
                //$this->load->view('/registration/daftar', $data1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my form

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Daftar</title>
    <body>
    <?php
    ?>
        <h1><center>Daftar</center></h1>
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('registration/registration/add_user'); ?>
        <center>
            Username <br>
            <input type="text" name="username"> <br>
            Password <br>
            <input type="password" name="password"> <br>
            Email <br>
            <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
            No Telepon <br>
            <input type="text" name="no_telepon"> <br>
            Alamat <br>
            <textarea name="alamat" rows="6" cols="23"></textarea> <br>
            </form>
            Foto
            <input type="file" name="foto"><br><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Daftar">
        </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't load helpers and libraries on views load them on controller or autoload.php

Comment: i have update my code sir, but the image name still returns empty in db, i am very confused, because the file path insert correctly into db, but why the file name not inserted

Answer (score 0):

Are you check your function `add_user()`?

I suggested you to check upload status before you can add to database. If your upload code error, they will show you error and then you will know where to fix it. It should be:

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('foto'))
{
    // Print the upload error
    var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
}else{
    $return = $this->upload->data();
    $image_name = $return['file_name'];
    // your code add to database
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: i have use your code sir, but when i insert the image name into db, file name still returns empty field, see my updated code, the file path insert success into db, but the image name still empty, there is no error code display on it

Comment: @AntonPrioHutomo can you show me structure of your database? Maybe it from your structure database